# Is it possible to pop a modal page and then immediately push a new one?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have tried this but it does not work

```
    private async void SignUpLink_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SignUp());
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible . You can use **[delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/delegates-lambdas)** to realzie it .I will show a sample with  *MainPage*/*SecondPage*/*ThirdPage* to show it.

Define a delegate in **PageA** and method to invoke it :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    //declare a delegate in MainPage
    public delegate void MyDelegate(bool val);

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // navigate to second page with delegate
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SecondPage(DeleagteVoid));
    }

    // invoked by poping back
    private async void DeleagteVoid (bool value)
    {
        //When delegate method invoked , by value to determine whether to push to next page
        Console.WriteLine("---" + value);
        if (value)
        {
           // if true , push to third page 
           await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ThirdPage());
        }
    }

}
```

**SecondPage** when poping to previous page invoke `delegate` method which in `MainPage` :

```
public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
{
    // declare delegate also in second page
    MyDelegate myDelegate;

    public SecondPage(MyDelegate deleagteVoid)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // assign delegate
        this.myDelegate = deleagteVoid;
    }


    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // pop to previous page
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        //invoke delegate method in MainPage
        myDelegate(true);
    }
}
```

**ThirdPage** do other you want .

Answer (score 1):

The modal page object is destroyed once it gets popped, so instead you can use this workaround, which works because when you PopModalAsync(), it will fire the OnAppearing() event in the calling page (the one from which you presented the modal page). So to do something after returning from a modal page, which in your case seems to be just presenting another modal page, you can:

```
public class NonModalCallingPage
{
    private bool ReturnedFromModalPage = false;


    private async void YourButtonClickedToOpenFirstModal (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReturnedFromModalPage = false;
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new FirstModalPage()));
        ReturnedFromModalPage = true;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (ReturnedFromModalPage)
        {
            ReturnedFromModalPage = false;
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SignUp());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but unfortunately when i step through the code the OnAppearing() event does not fire when the page is popped

Comment: It is firing for me and working as desired for your case on Android, iOS, and UWP using Xamarin.Forms version 4.2 - what platform and Xamarin Forms version are you not able to see this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the navigation using App.Current.MainPage.

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {           
     var mp = App.Current.MainPage;
     await mp.Navigation.PopModalAsync(); //PopModalAsync(false) if you want to skip animation
     await mp.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NewPage());                
 }
```