# Can't push new page right after popping modal page in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Trying to push a new page right after popping the modal page.

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ListOfPlayers());
}
```

So, `await Navigation.PopModalAsync()` is used for getting back to the root page while the second one function `await Navigation.PushAsync(new ListOfPlayers())` is used for pushing new page.

No errors occurred while compiling, but the problem is when `Button_Clicked` is being invoked only `await Navigation.PopModalAsync()` is giving any result and `await Navigation.PushAsync(new ListOfPlayers())` is being ignored. So, basically, I just getting back to the root page without being shown new page `new ListOfPlayers()`, when its creating was expected.

Comment: The page that launched the modal needs to be the one that pushes the new page

Comment: You need to use ` PushModalAsync` when you open that page with pushmodalasync.

Comment: You can check this answer by using the [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58021721/19335715).